# Program not being loaded

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have vb.net windows form application(.net 4.5), I have recently added a c# based class library project in the solution and one of the vb.net projects is referencing this project. When i build the solution in Debug any cpu mode everything works fine but when i build it in release any cpu mode I get the following exception

> Could not load file or assembly 'TagWriter, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. An
>   attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8996653/troubleshooting-badimageformatexception or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4340362/system-badimageformatexception-an-attempt-was-made-to-load-a-program-with-an-inc. Check your build configuration for Release.

Comment: My build configuration i.e the main solution build configuration is release any cpu and the tag writer project is also on release any cpu. I have checked all the configurations all are on the same configuration

Comment: Maybe delete `bin` folder, restart VS, try to rebuild? It is very probably not connected with mixing C# and VB.NET. The error comes during build or when you execute your app?

Comment: The solution build configuration name "AnyCPU" is completely meaningless to a VB.NET project.  Only the jitter forcing matters.  Which you surely forgot to change for the Release configuration.  Right-click the project, Properties, Compile tab.

Comment: .. > Advanced Compile Options > Target CPU to "AnyCPU". For C# it is Build tab > Platform Target. I can see "Any CPU" option there, so please @HansPassant what do you mean by saying that it is meaningless?