# AspNetCompiler - An attempt was made to load program with an incorrect format

Tags: c#, .net, compilation, compiler-errors, badimageformatexception

I am building a 64bit only web application (`AssemblyA`) and referencing another application I have built which is also 64bit only (`AssemblyB`).

When I add `AssemblyB` as a reference in `AssemblyA`, I get the following compilation error in Visual Studio:

> ASPNETCOMPILER Could not load file or assembly 'AssemblyB' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

Both of my application's platform target setting is set to `x64`, both Target Framework settings is `.Net Framework 4.6` and `Prefer 32bit is unchecked`.

I have tried referencing every dependent reference of `AssemblyB` in `AssemblyA`, making sure the versions of all dependent references are the same.

I have used this question: [How to determine if a .NET assembly was built for x86 or x64?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270531/how-to-determine-if-a-net-assembly-was-built-for-x86-or-x64) to confirm all referenced assemblies are either `MSIL` or `AMD64`.

I have used the `aspnet_compiler.exe` command line tool with the `errorstack` option enabled and got the following stack trace:

> [BadImageFormatException]: Could not load file or assembly 'AssemblyB' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
>
> at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntro spection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
>
> at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String code Base, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& s tackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntros pection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
>
> at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark &stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
>
> at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString,
>   Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark &stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection)
>
> at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark &stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection)
>
> at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString)
>
> at System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective)
>
> [ConfigurationErrorsException]: Could not load file or assembly 'AssemblyB' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
>
> at System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective)
>
> at System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomain BinDirectory()
>
> at System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo ai)
>
> at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection compConfig)
>
> at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetPreStartInitMethodsFromReferencedAssemblies()
>
> at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String preStar tInitListPath, Boolean& isRefAssemblyLoaded)
>
> at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart()
>
> at System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, Host ingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException)

I have looked at the following related questions and none answer this question. Most relate to IIS configuration, which is not the case as this is a compilation error, or have the solution as setting the project to allow 32bit platform target, which is not suitable for my case:

- ["An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format" even when the platforms are the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023766/an-attempt-was-made-to-load-a-program-with-an-incorrect-format-even-when-the-p) (no good as uses IIS config)
- [Could not load file or assembly ... An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format (System.BadImageFormatException)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11370344/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-an-attempt-was-made-to-load-a-program-with-a) (no good as is a runtime error)
- [System.BadImageFormatException An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4340362/system-badimageformatexception-an-attempt-was-made-to-load-a-program-with-an-inc) (no good as uses 32bit solution)
- [Could not load file or assembly 'xxx' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1648213/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-xxx-or-one-of-its-dependencies-an-attempt-was) (no good as uses 32bit solution)

I am at a loss as to where to go from here. To reiterate, I **do not** want to set either of my projects to 32bit and this isn't a problem with IIS config as this is a compilation error.

I have also tried it on several different machines and on brand new applications with the same result.

How do I fix this compilation error?

Answer (score 7):

The directive `<AspNetCompiler />` takes an argument `ToolPath` that can be directed to the 64 bit version of `aspnet_compiler.exe`. This is described in [this blogpost](http://codedroppings.blogspot.com/2009/01/web-deployment-projects-targeting-x64.html). The gist of it, edit your csproj file:

Add the `ToolPath` attribute to the `AspNetCompiler` node:

```xml
<AspNetCompiler VirtualPath="temp" PhysicalPath="$(ProjectDir)" ToolPath="$(AspNetToolPath)" />
```

And where `MvcBuildViews` is defined, add the properties `FrameworkVersion` and `AspNetToolPath`, like this:

```xml
<MvcBuildViews>true</MvcBuildViews>
<FrameworkVersion>v4.0.30319</FrameworkVersion>
<AspNetToolPath Condition=" '$(Platform)' == 'x64'">$(windir)\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\$(FrameworkVersion)</AspNetToolPath>
```